# yum install php-mcrypt

Tags: php

I installed mcrypt via "yum install php-mycrypt" but php still says it can't find it. How do I configure php to find it?

Comment: What distribution/version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the list of php modules:

```
php -m
```

If it's not listed, and no error appears it's probably not being loaded. Check /etc/php.ini and /etc/php.d/* and add an "extension=" line if it's not their alread.

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted Apache?

```
service httpd restart
```

assuming CentOS/RHEL from the "yum".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `yum install php-mcrypt`

Or try listing/searching for it. `yum list php*`